# Calculate moving average (low pass filter) using fft in GRASS

Tags: grass-gis, average

I am interested in calculating a moving average for a raster in GRASS/QGIS. In other words, each cell needs to receive as value the average of its current value and the neighboring cells in a square (let's say 3 cells x 3 cells square).

I understand I can achieve that with `r.mfilter`, but I found this solution is pretty slow for large rasters or bigger filters (larger neighborhoods).

I notice GRASS has `i.fft` for fast fourier transform, which is super fast. I heard in theory one can calculate moving averages using fft, but I could not find an example for a 2d image, and I cannot wrap my head around the math to figure out on my own.

Does anyone can conceive way to use to calculate moving average with a 3x3 filter, using `i.fft`?

Comment: Did you try `r.neighbors` ?

Comment: Yes, that should do the job, see https://grass.osgeo.org/grass-stable/manuals/r.neighbors.html

Comment: On my understanding `r.neighbors` has a big issue: It is hard-coded to round the value to the nearest integer (on average did not test other modes). It is quite limiting when dealing with real values.